# How docker-compose parse the `command` string?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I ran the command:

```
docker-compose -p foo -f - up <<YAML
version: "3.8"
services:
  main:
    image: alpine
    command: echo x && y
YAML
```

### Expected

```
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container foo-main-1  Created                                                                                                                                    0.0s
Attaching to foo-main-1
foo-main-1  | x && y
foo-main-1 exited with code 0
```

### Actual

```
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container foo-main-1  Created                                                                                                                                    0.0s
Attaching to foo-main-1
foo-main-1  | x
foo-main-1 exited with code 0
```

I know `CMD` of `Dockerfile` supports `exec` form and shell form and expect `docker-compose.yml` would behave like `Dockerfile`, however, looks like `docker-compose` uses some hacky way to pass the `command` string.

| `command` | output |
| --- | --- |
| echo x y z | x y z |
| echo x && y | x |
| echo x | y | x |
| echo x; y | x |

### Question

1. Does `docker-compose` simply use a regular expression to remove everything after `;`, `&&` and `|`?
2. If not, how does `docker-compose` process the `command` string?

I would appreciate if you can also provide the source code reference of which line parsing `command` string.

https://github.com/docker/compose

### My Environment

```
λ docker -v
Docker version 20.10.22, build 3a2c30b
λ docker-compose -v
Docker Compose version v2.15.1
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. When I run your docker-compose command, it echoes `x && y`. I'm on Ubuntu with docker-compose 1.29.2 and docker 20.10.22.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with docker-compose v2.16.0.

Comment: I updated the post with my docker/docker-compose version. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Just to be sure, you have Docker Desktop. Correct? There are some pretty significant differences between the Docker Desktop compose and the non-Docker Desktop version.

Comment: I think Compose `command:` is just split on spaces, though I can't back that up with code right now.  It is a place where if you do need shell operators (like `&&` to run multiple commands) then you need to explicitly provide a `sh -c '...'` wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker Compose V2 has been rewritten in Go, and the way it parses 'command' is different from V1. Docker Compose V2 uses Go package 'go-shellwords' to parse the command line, with certain special characters being handled specifically, such as:

```
\`)(";&|<>
```

In the case of the string 'echo x && y', the '&' character breaks the Parser() loop and leads to the end of string parsing, resulting in the output terminating in 'echo x'.

Additionally, the shell form 'echo x && y' means 'echo x' and then execute 'y'. This may not be what you intended, so you can explicitly declare the command string as 'echo "x && y"' or '["sh", "-c", "echo x && y"]', depends on your specific needs.

If you're interested in learning more about how command strings are parsed by Docker Compose, you can refer to the source code, specifically:

1. https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/v2/cmd/compose/compose.go#L187

```
func (o *ProjectOptions) ToProject(services []string, po ...cli.ProjectOptionsFn) (*types.Project, error) {
...
    project, err := cli.ProjectFromOptions(options)
    if err != nil {
...
```

2. https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/blob/master/cli/options.go#L381

```
func ProjectFromOptions(options *ProjectOptions) (*types.Project, error) {
...
    project, err := loader.Load(types.ConfigDetails{
        ConfigFiles: configs,
        WorkingDir:  workingDir,
        Environment: options.Environment,
    }, options.loadOptions...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

3. https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/blob/master/loader/loader.go#L1156

```
var transformShellCommand TransformerFunc = func(value interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    if str, ok := value.(string); ok {
        return shellwords.Parse(str)
    }
    return value, nil
}
```

4. https://github.com/mattn/go-shellwords/blob/master/shellwords.go#L125

```
func (p *Parser) Parse(line string) ([]string, error) {
    args := []string{}
    buf := ""
    var escaped, doubleQuoted, singleQuoted, backQuote, dollarQuote bool
    backtick := ""
...
```

You can take a look at shellswords.go to see how command string is parsed by Parse() function.